# Dropdown option not being selected

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, selected

I have the following code to build a dropdown form field:

```
 if ($current_user->ID) {
    $output .= '
<form action="" method="POST" class="profileForm" onSubmit="return validateMobile()">
<div class="formField">
  <label for="tenant_title">Title</label>
  <select name="tenant_title">
    <option value="Mr"' . titleSelected('Mr') . '>
    Mr
    </option>
    <option value="Miss"' . titleSelected('Miss') . '>
    Miss
    </option>
    <option value="Mrs"' . titleSelected('Mrs') . '>
    Mrs
    </option>
    <option value="Ms"' . titleSelected('Ms') . '>
    Ms
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And this function that checks what's already in the database:

```
function titleSelected($value){
    if ($tenant_details->tenant_title == $value) return 'selected';
return false;
}
```

The problem is it always defaults to 'Mr', which is the first option, regardless of what's in the database.

What am I missing?

I'm still very much a newbie with php, so please be gentle... :)

Comment: <option value="Ms" <?php echo titleSelected('Ms'); ?>>

Comment: I cannot use this as my code is already inside a function, and being returned as $output... It is not an HTML form.

Comment: Well that wasn't in your original post, did you manage to fix your problem?

Comment: @Naruto Sorry, not found a solution yet.

Comment: Hi OP, check this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CXtqx3ev), this works for me, but I replace the values in the function + made a change , no more return false but just return empty string... Should work..

Comment: @Naruto I checked your code, but it still doesn't work. I put the whole function in this pastebin (http://pastebin.com/wXAbtfP4), can you have a look? This is driving me mental!

Comment: Can you show me a printscreen/output of what you are getting?

Comment: @Naruto You can see the printscreen of the form here (http://igproperty.co.uk/output.jpg). The output is going through fine and creating the form, but the dropdown is not selecting to reflect what's on the database (in the printscreen it was supposed to be 'Ms'). I tested and I can print the `$tenant_details->tenant_title` variable, but for some reason the `titleSelected` function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So there is no selected behind any of the options?

Comment: Nope, it is always defaulting to the first one (Mr).

Comment: var_Dump($tenant_details->tenant_title); ? What does this give you?

Comment: `var_Dump($tenant_details->tenant_title);` gives me the title that is stored on the database, in the case of the test tenant, Ms. In other words, everything is working as it should apart from the function `titleSelected()`.

Comment: then do a var_dump(titleSelected('Mr')); for every option you have..

Comment: @Naruto Sorry, but I don't follow your logic... There are 4 options for the tenant to choose from the first time they fill in the form. If they return to that form, I want the option that they chose previously to be selected. That's what the function `titleSelected()` is intended to do: check the value stored in `$tenant_details->tenant_title` and select that option on the form. How do I implement your solution?

Comment: Are you sure your value is being stored correctly then?

Comment: Yes, I can look into the database directly as you can see on this screenshot: (www.igproperty.co.uk/tenant.jpg).

Comment: When I'm kinda running out of ideas by now... I'm just guessing what might be wrong...

Comment: It's been driving me crazy... Can I write an `if` statement inside the function to test each variable instead using the function? I know it is not pretty, but I really need to get this sorted, just don't know how to put the `if`inside the form. Remember, I'm a newbie...

Comment: Well the strange part is this should be able to work... So I'm not sure why this isn't working for you?!

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is, try to var_Dump(titleSelected('Mr')); like this with ALL the options you have, and check what every option gives you..

Comment: This is returning `string(0) ""` for every option... :|

Comment: Which means $tenant_details->tenant_title == $value isn't correct...

Comment: And how is that possible, if all the other tenant data is coming through fine and showing on the form? Do I need to sanitise the string before the `$tenant_details->tenant_title == $value`?

Comment: No idea.. Normally you shouldn't but I guess there is something else wrong here.. But I can't know for sure... I'm also wondering how you are able to acces `$tenant_details->tenant_title` since it's not defined in the function...

Comment: I get the data from `$tenant_details = getTenantData();`, as you can see on line 6 of the function on here: (http://pastebin.com/wXAbtfP4). I think it has to do with being a drop down field, because if I put `$tenant_details->tenant_title` in a text field it works fine...

Comment: Try: http://pastebin.com/DMZU1uMK , I think you can't acces that value since it's outside of the functions scope... I'm pretty sure that's the problem...

Comment: Nope... not working either.

Comment: It worked!!! You made a minor mistake on your code: `if ($val1 == $val)` instead of `if ($val1 == $val2)`.

Comment: It's as I expected, I'll formulate an answer..

Comment: Thanks you VERY MUCH for sticking with me... You are a life saver.

Comment: No problem, I've created an answer to this question below with 2 ways of dealing with it and extra information about PHP variable scope.. Feel free to accept this so the question can be 'closed'. Btw, next time come look for me in the [PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), it will go somewhat faster and questions won't get this much wall of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you can't compare `$tenant_details->tenant_title` to a value, since the `$tenant_details` was requested outside your function. To learn more about scope of a variable check out [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

There are 2 ways of solving it:

1. You just pass the object into your function:

   ```
   titleSelected($tenant_details, 'Ms');

   function titleSelected($tenant_details->tenant_title, $val2){
       if ($tenant_details->tenant_title == $val) {
           return 'selected';
       }
       return "";
   }
   ```
2. Just pass the value alone and compare:

   ```
   titleSelected($tenant_details->tenant_title, 'Ms');

   function titleSelected($val1, $val2){
       if ($val1 == $val2) {
           return 'selected';
       }
       return "";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `selected` you should return `selected="selected"`, like this:

```
function titleSelected($value){
    if ($tenant_details->tenant_title == $value) return 'selected="selected"';
    return false;
}


<div class="formField">
  <label for="tenant_title">Title</label>
  <select name="tenant_title">
    <option value="Mr" <?php echo titleSelected('Mr'); ?>>
    Mr
    </option>
    <option value="Miss" <?php echo titleSelected('Miss'); ?>>
    Miss
    </option>
    <option value="Mrs" <?php echo titleSelected('Mrs'); ?>>
    Mrs
    </option>
    <option value="Ms" <?php echo titleSelected('Ms'); ?>>
    Ms
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Edited:**

```
function titleSelected($value){
    if ($tenant_details->tenant_title == $value) return 'selected';
    return false;
}

function some_function(){

    // your code

    $output = '';  // initialize $output somewhere outside of if block

    if ($current_user->ID){
        $output .= '
        <form action="" method="POST" class="profileForm" onSubmit="return validateMobile()">
            <div class="formField">
              <label for="tenant_title">Title</label>
              <select name="tenant_title">
                <option value="Mr"' . titleSelected('Mr') . '>
                Mr
                </option>
                <option value="Miss"' . titleSelected('Miss') . '>
                Miss
                </option>
                <option value="Mrs"' . titleSelected('Mrs') . '>
                Mrs
                </option>
                <option value="Ms"' . titleSelected('Ms') . '>
                Ms
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </form>';
    }
    return $output;
}

echo some_function();
```

Comment: I personally would not return false, but rather null as false can sometimes eval to 0

Comment: @SamSwift웃 true, but it's upto OP how he'll handle false in this case.

Comment: It made no difference. HTML5 will accept `selected` (it is already working on a different function).

Comment: @BrunoHannemann Okay, HTML5 will accept selected but the problem is you're returning `selected` from the function but you're not `echo`ing it. Did you test my answer?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul The code I posted is being returned from inside a function as a variable $output, so your code doesn't work... What would be the correct code if I am already inside a php statement? Can I use `echo`?

Comment: @BrunoHannemann You posted the question as HTML code, hence the answer. Please update your question first, because then only it'll be answerable.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I updated the code to include the beginning of the output. There's more further down, but is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @BrunoHannemann Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Sorry, but your solution is still not working. `$output` is already initializing outside the `if` block.